# Is it possible to make a grammar LL($1$) which recognizes palindroms?

Tags: formal-grammars

Is it possible to make an algebraic grammar LL($1$) which recognizes palindroms for an alphabet $\{a,b\}$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. The language of palindromes over any alphabet with at least two elements is not deterministic, and thus has no LR or LL grammar.

The language of even-length palindromes $L_{epal}=\{ww^R \mid w\in\Sigmạ^*\}$  is a classic example of a non-deterministic context-free language, and you can find the outline of a proof in [Hopcroft & Ullman](https://dl.acm.org/doi/book/10.5555/1196416) (and other standard texts). The restriction to even-length palindromes simplifies the proof, but it can be extended to the language of all palindromes $L_{pal}=\{w \mid w=w^R, w\in\Sigmạ^* \}$. Without doing more work, though, it's evident that $L_{epal}=L_{pal}\cap (\Sigma\Sigma)^*$, and deterministic CFLs are closed against intersection with regular languages.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you give me a source or an argument please?

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/118500/why-no-dpda-can-accept-palindrome-according-to-this-proof

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/11598/prove-no-dpda-accepts-language-of-even-lengthed-palindromes